# $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right)$ is not neigbourhood of points

Tags: real-analysis

$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right)$ is not neighborhood of points

I got smallest open interval $(0,1)$ this is intersection of all these open intervals. are there any point which does not have neighborhood ?

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $$0 \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right)$$

Proof:
For any $n>0$, $-\frac1n <0 < 1+ \frac1n$.

Hint: $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right) = [0, b]$$

can you identify $b$?

Comment: b=1 am i right? & how u got closed interval here can you explain?

Comment: yup, try to prove the two sets are equal to make sure we did not make any mistake.

Comment: as i put limit n tends to infinity i got (0,1) open set .how can u claim we get closed [0,1]

Comment: I proved that $0$ is inside right? We can't just substitute $n$ inside and claim that that is the answer.We have to prove that two sets are equal. So we still have to prove a few things, prove that $1$ is inside, prove that anything outside the interval $[0,1]$ is not in the intesection.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ I_n=\left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right). $$
Noting $I_1\supset I_2\supset I_3\supset\cdots$, 
one has
$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left( - \frac1n, 1+ \frac1n \right)=\lim_{N\to\infty} \bigcap_{n=1}^N I_n=\lim_{N\to\infty} I_N=[0,1].$$